# atomicity of pthread_cond_wait()'s unlock-and-wait?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

How atomic is the unlock-and-wait of `pthread_cond_wait()` call?
Is there a window where mutex is already unlocked but the thread is not yet in the part where it is actually waiting and able to receive notifications?
IOW, is there a potential for missed wakeups in the `pthread_cond_wait()` function itself?

Comment: It makes no sense to ask, "how atomic."  An operation either _is_ atomic or it is _not_.  There are no shades of grey.  If there was a window in which the `wait()`ing thread could miss the signal--no matter how small--then the unlock-and-wait step would _not_ be atomic.  Fortunately for you,... (see zwol's answer, below.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [POSIX.1-2008 specification of `pthread_cond_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) addresses this question in its second paragraph:

> These functions [`pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_timedwait`] atomically release *mutex* and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable *cond*; atomically here means "atomically with respect to access by another thread to the mutex and then the condition variable". That is, if another thread is able to acquire the mutex after the about-to-block thread has released it, then a subsequent call to `pthread_cond_broadcast()` or `pthread_cond_signal()` in that thread shall behave as if it were issued after the about-to-block thread has blocked.

So, to first order, the answer is "yes, it's atomic", but pay careful attention to the last sentence.  There is no missed-wakeup window as long as the call to `pthread_cond_broadcast` or `pthread_cond_signal` comes from a thread *that successfully acquired the mutex after the sleeping thread released it*, and then, perhaps, released it again.  If the call comes from a thread that has not acquired the mutex at least once since it was released, the wakeup might get lost.

Comment: In the caveat case, it's not so much that the wakeup is "lost" as that it's simply *not ordered with respect to the wait* and therefore possibly happens "before" it.

Comment: @R, a signal that happens before any other thread waits for it is _lost_.  That is the reason why there must always be some _explicit_ and _thread safe_ way for the waiting thread to test the condition that it awaits.  I.e., the waiter should lock the mutex, perform the explicit test, and then only call pthread_cond_wait() if the test fails.

Comment: Worth remembering, the out of order notification discussed at the end should be no concern. If the notifying thread hasn't acquired the lock it must not have changed the dependent data. since it was last examined under the mutex.